# unzip and copy file from web to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to copy the file directly from web to s3 bucket.

https://www.ncua.gov/analysis/credit-union-corporate-call-report-data/quarterly-data

I want to unzip and copy 2019 march data from the above link to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write a shell script which will do something like this :

```
curl -O https://www.ncua.gov/files/publications/analysis/call-report-data-2019-03.zip
```

or

```
wget https://www.ncua.gov/files/publications/analysis/call-report-data-2019-03.zip
```

This will download the zip file onto your terminal. Then unzip it using below command :

```
unzip call-report-data-2019-03.zip
```

And then use below command to send it to S3:

```
aws s3 cp call-report-data-2019-03 s3://<bucket-name> --recursive
```

Let me know if anything else is required.